# dynamically add JLabels to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to build an GUI application with Java Swing. There is a button which adds a new `JLabel` on click. That's working well, but when the number of labels increases more than the panel size, I can't scroll down.

When I tried to add a `JScrollPane` it also doesn't scroll.

How can I create scroll pane which scrolls down when a new component is added?

### Code to add a new label

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello "+i);
label.setBounds(50, y, 100, 100);
pnl.add(label);
pnl.repaint();
y+=10;
i++;
```

### The design

[image]

Comment: Use a JList inside a JScrollPane instead of trying to add multiple JLabels. This situation is exactly what this component was built for.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). A scroll pane will not work with a null layout. Your panel needs to use a layout manager.